# How should I express this set of statements with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I set up a complex application which uses Entity Framework related to some Microsoft SQL Server databases. While it seems simple to express some common queries with Linq, I wonder how should I express this set of statements correctly (it is returning a scalar):

```
DECLARE @TZ SMALLINT;

SELECT @TZ = DATEPART(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET());
SELECT CAST(@TZ / 60 AS VARCHAR(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the c# equivalent:

```
DateTime n = DateTime.Now;
int tz = (n - n.ToUniversalTime()).Hours;
```

Of cource is assumes that your server and the program is in the same timezone.

Comment: They aren't. EF runs on a AspNet WebApi in Italy and it connects to various servers worldwide.

Comment: Then go the long way: create a function which return this value and add a computed column with this function. See below.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full code I mentioned above:

```
Create Function dbo.TimeZone(@dummy varchar) returns varchar(5)
as
begin
    Declare @tz varchar(5)
    Select @tz = CAST(DATEPART(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) / 60 AS VARCHAR(5))
    return @tz
End
Go

Create Table x ( i int,
tz as (dbo.Timezone('')) 
)
Go

Insert into x(i) Values(5);

Select * from x;
```

Or using a view:

```
Create View y as Select dbo.TimeZone('') Tz
Go

Select * From y
```